# HTML script, change how URL is displayed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

EDIT: I was able to use the advice below and add it in using an Anchor.

See if I can ask this correctly. I have this script in a Google sheet that send out an HTML email. There is a link included in the email that is displayed as the full URL. I would like to know if there is a way to change what the URL is displayed as. So instead of website/test/example.com it would just say Click Here or in my case Link to Dashboard.

```
    function triggermenu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Trigger Menu')
  .addItem('Create Trigger', 'createFormSubmitTrigger')
  .addToUi();
}

function createFormSubmitTrigger(funcname) {
  var funcname=funcname||'form1Submit';
  if(!isTrigger(funcname)) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onFormSubmit().create();
  }
}

function form1Submit(e) {
      if(e.values && e.values[1] && e.values[2]) { 
      var html='<style>td,th{padding:overflow-wrap: break-word;}table{table-layout:fixed;width:100%;}</style><table>';
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan ="2"><font size="4" color="red"><b>%s</b></font></td><td style="text-align:left">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','**** DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL ****','&nbsp;' );
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td style="text-align:left">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td style="text-align:left">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan ="2">%s</td><td style="text-align:left">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Please review findings','&nbsp;' );
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td colspan ="2"><font size="5"><b>%s</b></font></td><td style="text-align:left">%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','PROCESS LEADER AUDIT','&nbsp;' );
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Date and Time of Audit:',e.values[0]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Auditor:',e.values[1]); 
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Employee Audited:',e.values[2]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Line/Location Audited:',e.values[3]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong><font color="green">%s</font></strong></td><td><font color="green">%s</font></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Work Instructions Available:',e.values[4]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong><font color="green">%s</font></strong></td><td><font color="green">%s</font></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Work Instructions Being Followed Correctly:',e.values[5]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Work Instructions Comment:',e.values[6]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong><font color="blue">%s</font></strong></td><td><font color="blue">%s</font></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Standard Work Available:',e.values[7]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong><font color="blue">%s</font></strong></td><td><font color="blue">%s</font></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Standard Work Followed Correctly:',e.values[8]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Standard Work Comment:',e.values[9]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','If Any Findings Lead or Supervisor Contacted:',e.values[13]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong><font color="orange">%s</font></strong></td><td><font color="orange">%s</font></td></tr>','&nbsp;','Safety Findings:',e.values[10]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Safety Findings Comment:',e.values[11]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Additonal Comments:',e.values[12]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Follow Up Audit Needed:',e.values[14]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><strong>%s</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','Follow Up to Audit Number:',e.values[15]);
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );//empty line
        html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QcMXkoErEGUAepdzmXThKWrXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYY">Link to Dashboard</a></td><td>%s</td></tr>','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','&nbsp;' );
        html+='</table>';
    Logger.log(html);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(getGlobal('form1Email'), getGlobal('form1Subject'), '', {htmlBody:html});
  }
}
```

I'm sure I did something wrong in this post, hopefully there is a simple way to tell the URL to have a specific display text?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Have you tried to add an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)?

Comment: I'm not good with scripts or HTML. This script was written for me by someone on here. I don't know how or where I would put the anchor. right now it uses var url to set the ULR as a variable and then puts that in the last line '&nbsp;',url,'&nbsp;'

Comment: @esqew thanks I was able to make the anchor work. I updated the code.